# Multiple SqlDependencies firing the same OnChange Event

Tags: appfabric, sqldependency

I have a product catalog with a few hundred categories in it and I am dynamically creating an SqlDependency for each category in the catalog. The SqlCommands that these dependencies will be based on, will differ only on the categoryID. The problem that I have is that I want all these dependencies to perform different actions depending on the SqlDependency that fired them. How can I do that? Do I have to create a different OnChange event for each SqlDependency? Is there a way all these dependencies to fire the same OnChange event and this event to know which dependency fired it or receive a parameter which will be passed during the dependency creation?

This problem arised trying to create a Sql Dependency mechanism that will work with AppFabric Cache.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How many tables are you monitoring for change? You can specify OnChange event for each sql separately.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can look into the cache tables that asp.net is creating for you and the triggers that are being created on the original tables. Once you see what is going on, you can create the tables and triggers yourself and can implement the caching through your own asp.net code. It really is not that hard. Then, not when a table is updated(when you use SQLDependency), but relevant rows in that table are updated, you can refresh the relevant cache or write your own code to perform the whatever unique actions you want. Better off doing it yourself when you learn how to!